# Generic parameter passing from one obj to the other

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns

my case is : a save method in `ResourceService<T , ID >`

```
public interface IResourceService<T,ID>

public class ResourceService<T , ID> implement IResourceService<T,ID>
{
   public void save(T entity) throws RuntimeException {

    try {
        AsyncServiceSaveRunable<T> task = new
AsyncServiceSaveRunable<T>(getService(),entity);

        this.treadPoolExcutor.submitTask(task);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


   }
}
```

and in

```
public class AsyncServiceSaveRunable<T> implements Runnable  {
private IResourceService<?,?> service; //----> this is 
private Method serviceMethod;
private List<T> parameters;

public AsyncServiceSaveRunable(IResourceService<?,?> service,  List<T> parameters){ 
}

public AsyncServiceSaveRunable(IResourceService<?,?> service, T parameter)
                            throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException{

    this.service         = service;

    this.parameters = new ArrayList<T>();
    this.parameters.add(parameter);
}
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        if(this.parameters.size()>1)
            service.saveList(this.parameters);
        else
            service.save( this.parameters.get(0));
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
 }
```

the problem is service.saveList(this.parameters); and  service.save(...); 
are wrong

is there anyway to pass that parameter 
or i need a different of structure to deal this kind of case?

Thanks

------------------error message from eclipse ------------------------

```
The method save(capture#7-of ?) in the type IResourceService<capture#7-of ?,capture#8-of ?>
 is not applicable for the arguments (T)
```

Comment: What do you mean *"are wrong"*? Also, please edit your question to replace all your custom class types with standard ones from the JDK, so that it still shows us the problem, but  so we can copy it into our editors and compile it without having to have your special libraries. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: btw, I'd simplify the service API to have just `saveList()` (remove `save()` - if callers only have one item they can wrap it in a list themselves)

Comment: i have modified my question thanks for the comment and the wrong means  compile error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `ResourceService<T extends BaseEntity, ...>` you require `T` to be drevied from `BaseEntity`.

In `public class AsyncServiceSaveRunable<T>` `T` has no restrictions.

Then in `service.save(this.parameters.get(0));` you try to pass the (unbounded) generics type to a function that requires a `BaseEntity` object (or one derived from it).

You can require the type parameter of `AsyncServiceSaveRunable` to be derived from BaseEntity as well:

```
public class AsyncServiceSaveRunable<T extends BaseEntity>
```

UPDATE:
The error message is that the first type parameter of `IResourceService` is not valid for the type required by `save()`.  Previously you had the type parameter bounded by `BaseEntry`, but this restriction is now missing.  Maybe you want to write: `IResourceService<? extends BaseEntity, ? extends Serializable>`?

Comment: thanks for the answer, i follow your words and change AsyncServiceSaveRunable<T>  to AsyncServiceSaveRunable<T extends BaseEntity>  it still cannot compile

Comment: do you think the reason i got this error is : private IResourceService<?,?> service; ?

Comment: i change that to private IResourceService<? extends BaseEntity,?  extends Serializable> service;  still the same error    "The method save(capture#7-of ? extends BaseEntity) in the type IResourceService<capture#7-of ? extends BaseEntity,capture#8-of ? extends Serializable> is not applicable for the arguments (T)"

Comment: Have you changed `AsyncServiceSaveRunable<T>` to `AsyncServiceSaveRunable<T extends BaseEntity>` as well?

Comment: yes  have changed to "public class AsyncServiceSaveRunable<T extends BaseEntity> implements Runnable "

Comment: Then try `IResourceService<T, ? extends Serializable>` (replaving all other occurrances of IResourceService as well)